# How to pass a function as a parameter in a JAVA SDK Operation for mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-sdk

I am trying to build a custom connector using [Mule's Java SDK](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started). Basically what I am trying to do is to add functionality to the current cache scope to let the developers to be able to add a condition upon which the scope should store something in the cache based on the final result (and some other features too, but this is what I am mainly stuck at). For example only store a database query response if the result is not empty.
To do this I am thinking to pass a function as an argument in the operation which will return a Boolean and on the basis of the result the operation will store the result in the cache. The final function definition of the operation would look something like this

```
public void cache(String key, Function(or something else?) storeInCache, Chain connectors, CompletionCallback<Object, Object> callback) {}
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do. I am open to any suggestions. May be there is any alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can 'extend' a built-in component like the cache scope. Maybe you can just use an expression for that argument. If that doesn't work for your use case, other methods could be either use a [dynamic configuration](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/static-dynamic-configs#dynamic-config-expiration) or alternatively  define storeInCache to be a [ParameterResolver<>](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/special-parameters#parameter-resolver) to defer the execution of an expression.

Comment: I can not use  expression for that argument because that will be calculated before calling the java method, and will pass the final value, what I am looking is that it accepts the expression, but it executes at the very end of the flow, and on the basis of that I can decide if I store the result in cache or not.

Comment: Did you check the documentation for ParameterResolver? "ParameterResolver<Type> allows you to defer the resolution of an expression on an operation. This is useful when a parameter that takes an expression as a value is not required. You can improve performance by resolving such an expression on demand from within the connectors’s code instead of resolving it automatically."

Comment: Yes, I am trying that out. I mostly want to check if it will execute on the new Payload or on the previous payload only. But yes, it looks something that could work.

Comment: I tried it, it gives the ability to execute the expression but it still executes on the payload which was before entering the scope

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what is the new payload here. Perhaps you can expand in the question adding some code example and clarifications.

Comment: By new payload I mean the response from DB call, on which I want to check if it is empty then not store in cache. But the ParamenterResolver is getting executed on the payload which was invoked prior to the cache scope.